# Fineuploader Progress Bar FileSize calculation

Tags: fine-uploader

Quick query:

I've noticed that on the default progress bar, the filesize calculation for the file seems to be calculated as bytes / 1000 / 1000, rather than / 1024 / 1024.

Is this intentional, or a bug? Or possibly a setting I've missed?

For example, a 347mb file as reported by Windows shows in the progress bar as it's uploading as 364mb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IEEE is pretty clear that 1 MB = 1000000 bytes. While some OSes don't follow this definition, such as Windows, others do, such as OS X. Here is one such reference: http://physics.nist.gov/cuu/Units/binary.html. It is clear that there are those in both camps (powers of 2 and powers of 10) that are willing to argue their side. That said, I'm for not changing the code as it follows a standard/codified definition.

Comment: Hi Ray - that's fine thanks. Just wanted to clarify that was indeed the case as a user pointed this out to me and worried something was amiss.